# php foreach iteration over object property array not incrementing the value

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, object-property

Please help! I have been staring at this for too long. I have a property of an object that is an array of objects. I want to pass in an object to a method of the parent object and search through that array property for a match, and if one is found return the index. Otherwise, I need it to return -1. For some reason, it is not iterating. If I echo out what should be the $order->product property (where the index is pointing during the loop), it is unchanging. I have dumped the array and I know it contains different values. I can show you a big var dump, but I figured I would first ask if there is a simple error or something else that is obvious to you that I have missed.

```
public function getItemIndex($prod) {
    if (isset($this->orders)){
      foreach($this->orders as $key => $order) {
        if ($order->product == $prod) { //if I echo this $order->product to the screen, it is unchanging
          return $key;
        } else { return -1; }
      }
    }
    else {
      return -1;
    } 
  }
```

If anyone has any ideas, I am open to discuss and post more information as needed. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can you show `$this->orders` (or part of it)?

Comment: in_array just returns a boolean. I'll add the var_dump, one sec...

Comment: as in `if (!in_array((array)$this->orders, $prod)) return -1;` EDIT, Oh you want the key.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are ALWAYS `return`ing a value on the first iteration, either the `$key` or `-1`. Try removing the `else` statement that you currently have. This will allow you to fully iterate over the entire array.

```
public function getItemIndex($prod) {
    if (isset($this->orders)){
        foreach($this->orders as $key => $order) {
            if ($order->product == $prod) { //if I echo this $order->product to the screen, it is unchanging
                return $key;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This will ONLY `return -1` once it has iterated over everything and found nothing to match. It will still `return $key` if it finds a match.

Comment: Shouldn’t it be `return -1;`? You seemed to have missed the semicolon.

Comment: Indeed, it has been fixed.